# inline-block div not initially expanding with content

Tags: html, css

Alright, I've been smashing my head against this wall for a while.

I have a tab that sits at the top of the page underneath the navbar. The tab displays a "login" link, or, if they are logged in, their username and a "logout" link.

The tab (`user-tab`) is set to `display:inline-block; width:auto;`, which works partially, but the last child element always gets cutoff partially, at least until either: 1) the window is refreshed, 2) the window is resized, or 3) I try changing the CSS via the web inspector. After I do any of those three things, it starts behaving normally. It's the same behaviour in all major browsers.
I've tried the `overflow:hidden` trick, I've tried removing padding, letting white-space be normal; **nothing works**.

It should look like:

```
______________________________________
|  John Doe    My Offers     Logout  |
--------------------------------------
```

But instead looks like:

```
_______________________________
|  John Doe    My Offers     Logout 
-------------------------------
```

Here's the code:

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 83%;
}
.user-tab {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  /* overflow:hidden; */
  display: inline-block;
  right: 2%;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0.35% 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background:#f00;
}
.user-tab a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="user-tab">
      <a href="">
        <span class="icon-user"></span>
        John Doe
      </a>


      <a href="">
        <span class="icon-cart"></span>
        My Offers
      </a>
 
      <a href="">
        <span class="icon-cancel-circle"></span>
        Logout
      </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

What is happening and how come none of the fixes are working? It clearly understands how it is supposed to work, but only after I "wake it up".

EDIT: Funnily enough, it doesn't have this issue in the "Run Snippet" section, but in the jsFiddle linked below, it is reproducing the issue.

Comment: Is http://jsfiddle.net/s4x89e5L/ how it looks on your screen? Is this all of the css you have for this?

Comment: I can't reproduce. The result doesn't look like neither of those. Why `with:auto`, that's the initial value. Why `display: inline-block` with absolute positioning, it will compute to `block`.

Comment: Please include all of the css needed to reproduce the issue

Comment: @Huangism Not quite. I updated it and now it is reproducing the problem I am having

Comment: @Oriol Ahh, so it does. Thanks for that tip. still haven't found a workaround, but that's giving me something new to follow up on, thanks.

Comment: @DanTheGameMan http://jsfiddle.net/s4x89e5L/7/ does that look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal padding percentage on `.user-tab a` seems to be causing the problem, trying using `em` or `px` instead.

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 83%;
}
.user-tab {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0.35% 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.user-tab a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="user-tab">
    <a href="">
      <span class="icon-user"></span>
      John Doe
    </a>


    <a href="">
      <span class="icon-cart"></span>
      My Offers
    </a>

    <a href="">
      <span class="icon-cancel-circle"></span>
      Logout
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that did it. 
So now the question is: does anyone know WHY having percentile padding in this circumstance causes that behaviour? Or is that just one of the many mysteries of CSS that we'll never quite understand?

Comment: Probably some crazy edge case layout problem when positioning absolutely or something. I'd just stay away from `%` in padding and forget about it :P

Comment: @DanTheGameMan It's because you did not specify a width for `user-tab` so it would normally wrap the last item to the next line but you have no-wrap so it forced the last item to be on the same line which produces your issue

Comment: @Huangism but why would the width of `.user-tab` be constrained? And why does it fix itself up after a reflow?

Comment: @DanielImms I think it's because when it loads, it calculates the padding on the anchor based on the width not taking into the padding on the anchor. So it's short to begin with which causes the wrapping but with no-wrap you see what you saw. So if you set a finite padding with px for example, the calculation will not be wrong so it does not wrap. If you set a width on the container of the anchors then it will look correct and no need to set the no-wrap

Answer (score 1):

You could try to replace `position:absolute` with `float: right`, as absolute positioning can have some interesting side-effects that can be a pain to figure out, and `float: right` very simply floats the element to the right. You can add margin to the element if you want it a little bit over (similar to right: 2%)

Comment: Gave it a try, still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

FYI When you use padding in percentages along with width/height etc. you are causing yourself grief. Especially with an ie browser. ie adds the padding to the size of the div see this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp
Best way to avoid issues is to avoid horizontal padding if you have assigned a width and add margins/padding to the element inside it.

Get rid of the float OR the absolute, that doesn't make sense.

You can also use position relative and just make it have a negative top margin to your desire if you choose to keep the float.

Make sure you ad overflow:visible to your container, that might be why it is cutting it off.